# Restored model in tensorflow and predictions

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow

I created model in tensorflow of neural network.
I saved the model and restore it in another python file.

The code is below:

```
def restoreModel():
    prediction = neuralNetworkModel(x)
    tf_p = tensorFlow.nn.softmax(prediction)
    temp = np.array([2,1,541,161124,3,3])
    temp = np.vstack(temp)

    with tensorFlow.Session() as sess:
        new_saver = tensorFlow.train.import_meta_graph('model.ckpt.meta')
        new_saver.restore(sess, tensorFlow.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
        all_vars = tensorFlow.trainable_variables()

        tensorFlow.initialize_all_variables().run()
        sess.run(tensorFlow.initialize_all_variables())
        predict = sess.run([tf_p], feed_dict={
            tensorFlow.transpose(x): temp,
            y : ***
        })
```

when "temp" variable in what I want to predict!
X is the vector shape, and I "transposed" it to match the shapes.
I dont understand what I need to write in `feed_dict` variable.

Answer (score 2):

I am answering late but maybe it can still be useful. `feed_dict` is used to give tensorflow the values you want your placeholders to take. `fetches` (the first argument of `run`) is the list of results you want. The keys of `feed_dict` and the elements of `fetches` must be either the names of the tensors (I didn't try it though) or variables you can get by

```
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
var = graph.get_operation_by_name('name_of_operation').outputs[0]
```

Maybe `graph.get_tensor_by_name('name_of_operation:0')` works too, I didn't try.

By default, the name of placeholders are simply 'Placeholder', 'Placeholder_1' etc, following the order of creation in the graph definition.